# values - invalid resource directory name

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, directory, multiscreen

I'm getting `"invalid resource directory name"` error at `values-normal-mdpi-land` directory. What is interesting everything was fine until I started working on a project in different computer.

**Maybe some sdk tools are missing?**

What can cause this?

I have also `values-normal-mdpi` folder in my project which doesn't throw any error.

Comment: have you change tool for development ?

Comment: nope, i just cloned project from repository but I'm still working with Android Studio

Comment: ... is the `normal` modifier mandatory?

Comment: hmm if i remember well it differentiated mobile from tablet what I need

Comment: maybe values-normal-mdpi-land is not supported anymore, I updated SDK, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Aren't you strangely **mixing** between the `values-normal` and the `values-mdpi` folders?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

> **Project --> Clean**

check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Update to latest android studio ,by default it is providing **values**  and **drawable** .

so if you update studio it may resolve your problem.

Comment: do you have created your own directory values-normal-mdpi-land ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have that you can still see the name of your folder.

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), you must respect the order of priority of conditions : land must be placed before mdpi

[image: doc android]

I think you must have `values-land-mdpi`because normal and mdpi are duplicate (normal = mdpi).